# Fips_validation request File example

Tags: dpdk

I am running dpdk on x86 and I running one application fips_valudation. I just want to know how to give. .req file for that application

Answer (score 0):

According to the dpdk fips_validation docs:

```
./fips_validation [EAL options] -- --req-file FILE_PATH/FOLDER_PATH
```

For more info refer here: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/fips_validation.html